# Java UTF-8 special characters to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java, encoding, utf-8

I have a Java Web Application(Webwork) and I have some .jsps which show some data that can be special (UTF-8) characters. Ex:Jérôme Serrano

The .jsps include the correct UTF-8 headers:

- in my jsp I include a *decorator.jsp* which has `<%@ page  pageEncoding="UTF-8" contentType="text/html;charset=utf-8" %>`
- *decorator.jsp* in turn includes a *meta.jsp* which looks like:

```html
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

In .jsp I read my data like:

```
<ww:property value="%{content.author}" />
```

and it is correctly displayed:
[image]

I try  to pass the string to JS, so that after the page is loaded I do something else(like call another service when the user clicks a button)

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
var contentData = {};
contentData.author = "<ww:property value="%{content.author}" />";
alert(contentData.author);
</script>
```

BUT in JS the characters are not displayed correctly!
[image]

So why when the .jsp is loaded the characters are rendered correctly, but once we pass them into JS they are broken?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After debugging and struggling with this whole night, here is my solution:
- instead of writing values from Java directly into JavaScript variables like:

```
<script charset="UTF-8">
var myName = "<ww:property value="name" />";
alert(">>" + myName);
</script>
```

in which case char encoding is not working properly.

I write Java values into *hidden input* . This also has the benefits of automatically escaping chars like: '(apostrophe), " (quote) , etc...

```
<input id="name_in" type="hidden" value="<ww:property value="name" />">
<script>
    var elem = $('#name_in').val();
    alert(">>"+elem);
</script>
```

In this case encoding works perfectly! Also there is no need to JS escape chars like: ' and "

Answer (score 0):

An external JavaScript with an UTF-8 character set:

```js
<script src="myscripts.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
```

or internal :D !

```js
<script charset="UTF-8"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to save your files using the option "Save with encoding" on your code editor.
I know that Sublime Text has this option (File -> Save with encoding).

You can try different encodings. UTF-8 or ISO-8859-1.

The idea is, you have to save the file using the same encoding which the headers (meta) is.